Calling a list from a different file through a .isin() method
I am reworking a script I built to add values to a .csv file.  Towards the bottom I have a check function for duplicate data (if same mm/yyyy and Client Acronym are present in the .csv file, don't write into the csv file for the data being selected from excel).  I this worked with 3 clients I put into the Client as r['ABCD','AABC','DDAC'] into the .isin() function.  However, the client list is 100 plus, so I turned it into a list in a different file named clients.py
When I go to call this list in to the client .isin function, it is not reading the list for some reason. Not sure where to start other than a for loop. If that's the case, I will start working on that.
import pandas as pd
import csv
import openpyxl

from clients import unique_clients_main

import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)

actuals_csv = r'C:\Users\goonsquad\Documents\Python Test Files\Excel\Client Actuals.csv'
read_actuals = r"C:\Users\goonsquad\Documents\Python Test Files\Excel\Client Actuals Import.xlsx"


#reading/importing csv file into Pandas data frame
df_actuals = pd.read_csv(actuals_csv)

read_wb = read_actuals

#importing actuals from spreadsheet into dataframe
df_actualsimport = pd.read_excel(
    io = read_wb,
    sheet_name = "Actuals Import",
    usecols='A:E',
    skiprows=2,
    header=0,
)

#changing data type for the given columns
columns = ['Month Actuals', 'Entity', 'AccountName']
for i in columns:
    df_actuals[i] = df_actuals[i].astype('|S')

#creating bool checks for True
Client = df_actuals.astype(str).isin([unique_clients_main]).any().any()
Month = df_actuals.astype(str).isin([r'12024']).any().any()
check = [Client == True,
         Month == True]

if all(check):
    print("Values exist already.")

else:
    print("Values don't exist.")
    df_actualsimport.to_csv(
        actuals_csv,
        mode = 'a',
        header = False,
        encoding = 'utf-8',
        index = False,
        date_format = '%#m/%d/%Y')


Why is unique_clients_main surrounded by [[ ]] Shouldn't it be .isin(unique_clients_main) ?

Oh yea, you're right.  I added that thinking it would help.  I'll take it out as it wasn't apart of the original code.

Can you print the value of unique_clients_main, and make sure that it is what you expect?

Yea, when I print the list, it shows values, and also printing the type gives me <class 'str'>

Huh? Shouldn't the type be <class 'list'> if it's a list?

I'm wondering if the strings are off, and its including the singles quotes in the string, when I go to put in the .astype method.  When I print the array, its showing in the terminal as follows: ['ABCD', 'AABC', 'DDAC']

Im checking the types within the list. Not the list itself with [type(item) for item in unique_clients_main]
